# how to rename a variable in perl

Tags: perl

I would like rename a variable dynamically, Is there any way to do this in perl.

Thanks
Praveen

Comment: Explain what you actually want to achieve by doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)? This gives you a reference to an existing object. Probably good enough.

Or, do you want to use a [Type Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)? This allows you to directly modify the symbol table. There's probably no good reason for using it these days, but it does let you give a new name to an existing variable at a very fundamental level.

Comment: There are lots of good reasons for modifying the symbol table -- exporting, aliasing, run-time dispatching, etc.